# Cannot get trace output of the tracepoints I created in my module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to generate a trace for my module to track its working. My module is based on registering a bus under /sys/bus, then register device and driver under the bus.

I want to track the registration of each devices and fill the buffer trace in /sys/kernel/tracing. So, I used the TRACE_EVENT macro.

Here's my code files and what I have done so far.

trace-dev1ce.h file

```
#undef TRACE_SYSTEM
#define TRACE_SYSTEM trace-dev1ce

#undef TRACE_SYSTEM_VAR
#define TRACE_SYSTEM_VAR trace_dev1ce
/*
 * For re-reading of this file, following function is needed
 *      || defined(TRACE_HEADER_MULTI_READ)
 */

#if !defined(_TRACE_EVENT_DEVICE_H) || defined(TRACE_HEADER_MULTI_READ)
#define _TRACE_EVENT_DEVICE_H

/* 
 * include <linux/tracepoint.h> for every trace
 *
 */

#include <linux/tracepoint.h>

/* Define event class for hooking different trace points to different 
 * events using DEFINE_EVENT_CLASS Macro
 */

DECLARE_EVENT_CLASS(linux_device_model,

                TP_PROTO(char *device, const char *name),

                TP_ARGS(device, name),

                TP_STRUCT__entry(
                        __array(char, device, 100)
                        __array(char, name, 100)
                ),

                TP_fast_assign(
                        strlcpy(__entry->device, device, 100);
                        strlcpy(__entry->name, name, 100);
                ),

                TP_printk("%s name = %s\n", __entry->device, __entry->name)
);

/* Define various events as an instance to the above define event class
 * using DEFINE_EVENT Macro.
 */

/* bus registration event */
DEFINE_EVENT(linux_device_model, bus,
                TP_PROTO(char *device, const char *name),
                TP_ARGS(device, name)
);

/* device registration event */
DEFINE_EVENT(linux_device_model, device,
                TP_PROTO(char *device, const char *name),
                TP_ARGS(device, name)
);

/* driver registration event */
DEFINE_EVENT(linux_device_model, driver,
                TP_PROTO(char *device, const char *name),
                TP_ARGS(device, name)
);

/* the if protection ends here */
#endif

/* define the include path and file for the trace to take place
 */

#undef TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH
#undef TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE
#define TRACE_INCLUDE_PATH /home/kerneltest

/* If TRACE_SYSTEM and filename is same, we don't need the TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE 
 */
#define TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE trace-dev1ce
#include <trace/define_trace.h>
```

here is my trace-dev1ce.c file (only header and init function)

```
/* The following macro will create the c code for the trace macros used */

#define CREATE_TRACE_POINTS
#include "trace-dev1ce.h"

static int __init dev_init(void)
{
        
        int err; 
        err = bus_register(&my_bus);
        if(err){
                printk(KERN_ALERT "bus registration error\n");
                return -1;
        }
        /* trace point here for tracking bus registration*/
        trace_bus("bus", my_bus.name);
        
        err = bus_create_file(&my_bus, &bus_attr_descr);
        if(err){
                printk(KERN_ALERT "attribute creation failed\n");
                return -1;
        }
        
        err = dev_register(&mydev);
        if(err){
                printk(KERN_ALERT "Device registration error\n");
                return -1;
        }
        /* Trace point here for tracking device registration*/
        trace_device("device", mydev.name);
        
        printk(KERN_INFO "DEVICE REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL\n");
        
        err = drv_register(&mydev.drv);
        if(err){
                printk("driver registration problem\n");
                return -1;
        }
        
        /* Trace point here to track driver registration */
        trace_driver("driver", mydev.drv.name);
        
        printk("driver registration successfull\n");
        return 0;
}
```

To enable tracing I did the following:

```
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# echo 1 > events/trace-dev1ce/enable 
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# cat events/trace-dev1ce/bus/enable 
1
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# cat events/trace-dev1ce/device/enable
1
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# cat events/trace-dev1ce/driver/enable
1
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# echo 1 > tracing_on
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing# cat trace
# tracer: nop
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 0/0   #P:6
#
#                                _-----=> irqs-off
#                               / _----=> need-resched
#                              | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                              || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                              ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID     CPU#  ||||   TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |         |   ||||      |         |
root@reb0rn:/sys/kernel/tracing#
```

Ideally , I should get the trace output when the bus, device and drivers are registered. But I don't know why I don't get the desired output.

I tried using `trace_printk` and then I get the desired trace

```
# tracer: nop
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 3/3   #P:6
#
#                                _-----=> irqs-off
#                               / _----=> need-resched
#                              | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                              || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                              ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID     CPU#  ||||   TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |         |   ||||      |         |
          insmod-5810    [005] ....  2171.169812: 0xffffffffc136c02c: bus name = mybus-1
          insmod-5810    [005] ....  2171.169825: 0xffffffffc136c097: device = mydev
          insmod-5810    [005] ....  2171.169858: 0xffffffffc136c103: driver name = mydev
```

I have checked available_events file where I have my required events. Also cat tracing_on outputs 1 indicating trcaing is on.

Any Ideas where did I went wrong?